# Range of rpg color start from R0 G0 B0 end with R255 G255 B255

Tags: html

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('s');

if (canvas.getContext) {

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

var data = imageData.data;
function paintGreen(data) {


  var numPixels = data.length / 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < numPixels; i += 5) {
    data[i * 5 + 1] = 100; 
    data[i * 4 + 3] = 900; 
  }

  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}
paintGreen(data);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="s" width="350", height="350" style="border:5px solid #ff305f;">
  Pixel manipulation: Change every 10th pixel to a solid green color.
</canvas>
```

This code shows 350*350 px's, at the moment it's full green.

What should I do if I want each px to take a color random from range of rpg start from R0 G0 B0 end with R255 G255 B255?

What should I add and where?

Comment: Why using `canvas`?

Answer (score 0):

In a normal way, you can add the color as `background-color` as I have demoed in the below snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var items = "";
  var max = 255;
  for(var i = 0; i<255; i++) {
    var red = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
    var blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
    var green = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
    var el = `<span class="item" style="background-color: rgb(${red}, ${green}, ${blue});"></span>`;
    items += el;
  }
  $("#wrapper").html(items);
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper' id="wrapper">
  
</div>
```

Comment: wow i like it when i click on run code snippet,
but i run it on https://codebeautify.org/htmlviewer its not working
sorry im new
can you show me the full code how it will be look like?
i just want to control the size of the px
and to size the width & height
but the colors will be random from full range of rpg

Comment: like i will just change the px size if 1 px or 5 px or 10 px, and i will change the width by height like 350px BY 350px or 650px BY 650

Comment: I don't get what you asked